# Monero CLi wallet Restore Height

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, block-height

I was restoring a wallet via monero cli and i set the restore height 2600000.
But it then started scanning the blockchain from the very beginning like 1/ 271xxxx, then 1999/271xxxx, so on and so forth. But i did pass the param into the command.

Experiment:
it didn't work on the cli monero. for the purpose of testing that feature, i then opened the same wallet file using feather wallet, it did start scanning from the height that i set.

What can be in the middle of the way?

Thanks!!

Comment: Another thing adding to my question raised above is that:
I tried resetting the height by typing in  "set refresh-from-block-height xxx" and then refresh, but it was still scanning from the very begining of the blockchain.

Comment: Please see the Q&A I linked, it is explained there. That is, 'It will pull block hashes up till the restore height and scan blocks from the restore height on.'